# Howto test with FluentAssertion if an object is equivalent to another with a property solidcolorbrush already set

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

I have a unit test with FluentAssertions, where I want to test an object equivalent.

```
[TestFixture]
public class TaskCompletionTest
{
        private string _callId;
        private List<Step> _steps;
        private SolidColorBrush _solidColor;

        [SetUp]
        public void ReInitializeTest()
        {
            _callId = _faker.Name.FullName();
            _steps = new List<Step> { new Step { Name = "Step1" }, new Step { Name = "Step2" } };
            _solidColor = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 0)); 
        }

                [Test]
        public void ShouldCreateTaskCompletion()
        {
            //Arrange
            var taskCompletion = new TaskCompletionwModel(_callId, _steps);

            //Acts
            var taskCompletionExpected = new
            {
                CallId = _callId,
                Steps = _steps,
                StatusColor = _solidColor
            };

            //Assert
            taskCompletionExpected.Should().BeEquivalentTo(taskCompletion);
        }
}       


public class Step
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TaskCompletionwModel
{
    public string CallId { get; private set; }
    public List<Step> Steps { get; private set; }
    public SolidColorBrush StatusColor { get; set; } = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 0));


    public TaskCompletionwModel(string callId, List<Step> steps)
    {
        CallId = callId;
        Steps = steps;
    }
}
```

When I run the test I have this.
Expected member StatusColor to be #FF000000, but found #FF000000.

With configuration:
- Use declared types and members
- Compare enums by value
- Match member by name (or throw)
- Without automatic conversion.
- Be strict about the order of items in byte arrays

Why this test doesn´t work?

Best regards.
Jolynice

Answer (score 3):

Hello I found the problem, I need to cast the type of the SolidColorBrush.

```
var taskCompletionExpected = new
{
   CallId = _callId,
   Steps = _steps,
   StatusColor = (SolidColorBrush) _solidColor,
};
```

Done,

Best regards.